# menu not visible when change language

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have a menu in the action bar that is visible if in the telephone is setted the english language(default), but for the italian (for which i have created only the folder values-it for the strings) the app doesn't show the action bar and the menu.. i initialize the menu with the classic way :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

where am i wrong? do i have to do another folder for the menu besides the standard folder "menu" in which i put all the menu (as "main" in my example)? thank you..

Comment: Which version of Android is running on your Italian phone?

Comment: android 4.1.1 on Alcatel one-touch 4030D

Comment: Actionbar should work for this phone. If you switch the same phone to English language then your Actionbar appears?

Comment: yes, exactly.. in italian i have a very little grey bar with the name of the app.. in english i have the bigger one also with menu.. is android racist? :D ahaha

Comment: And in Android emulator? Does it still work after switching to Italian?

Comment: i didn't try with the emulator.. i will do it tomorrow.. thank you

Comment: I resolved this issues removing :

      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

from the manifest in the tag "application"

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

I had a theme assigned and it was in conflict with my minSdkVersion=8

Comment: Perhaps you could post your comment as an answer, so as others can learn from your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issues removing : android:theme="@style/AppTheme" from the manifest in the tag "application"

```
     <application android:allowBackup="true" 
                  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I had a theme assigned and it was in conflict with my minSdkVersion=8